# Google Chrome: how to fetch "minimized" event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I try to fetch all events when the state of a window changes. So far, I use a content script that adds a "resize" listener to the window: `window.onresize = function() {...}`. This allows me to fetch when a window's state changes to "normal", "maximized" and "fullscreen".

However, I have no idea what to do to also get "minimized". Minimizing a window does not fire "resize" events. I tried to use the onFocusChanged API to add an listener, i.e., `chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(windowId) {...}));`, but it has its issues. Firstly, if the window I minimize has the focus, `windowId = -1 (chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE)`, so I cannot fetch the window to readout its state. And secondly, if the window doesn't have the focus, the `onFocusChanged` event is not fired.

In short, how can I detect when a Chrome window has been minimized?

Comment: I now use the following workaround: Beside the RESIZE event I also fetch the event when the browser window lost its focus - which also happens when the window is minimized. Thus, each time a window has lost its focus I check the window state. Analogously I check if the window state has changed of a window get back the focus. Combining both RESIZE and FOCUS events work quite well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Focus changed.");

    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window){
        console.log(window.state);
        if(window.state == "normal") {
            console.log("It's normal.Stop the watch.");
        } else if(window.state == "maximized"){
            console.log("It's maximized.Start the watch.");
        } else if(window.state == "minimized"){
        console.log("It's minimized.Start the watch.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work when window has just opened and after that immediately press the Maximize button. (chrome.windows.onFocusChanged will not fire)